# Need logic for summing numbers using Checkboxes in Android

Tags: android

can any one suggest me the logic to sum the numbers using the checkboxes in Android. For instance if checkbox1 have number 100 assigned to it, checkbox2 is assigned with number 200, checkbox 3 is assigned with 300 and checkbox4 is assigned with number 400.

If I select checkbox1 and checkbox3 I should get a Toast message showing the sum or if I choose the checkboxes 1,2,3 then I should get the sum of all the checkboxes that were checked.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section in the FAQ.  You need to show some efforts on your part before others will help.  Start doing the work, write some code - then, if you get stuck, post the code here and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example given in this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/) deals with similar stuff.

Use similar code for all your CheckBoxes.

```
chkBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkBox1 checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            sum += 100; // assuming the value of your first checkbox is 100
            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
               "Sum = " + sum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my quest, ur answer is valuable for me.

Comment: You are most welcome! Don't forget to upvote / accept my answer if it solved your problem. (It's the tick mark beside the top-left of my answer) Cheers! :)

Comment: sorry, bro I don't have enough reputations to voteup for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put on these checkboxes an on click event. Let's say you're using onclick="sumElm" in you xml  layout.
Then in your activity:

```
private int sum=0;

public void sumElm(final View view) {
             CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view;
             int n = Integer.getInteger(cb.getText());
             if(cb.isChecked())
                 this.sum+=n;
             else
                 this.sum-=n;

}
```

Assuming you use the text in the checkbox. Hope it helps! :)